# Conditional confirm box in c#

Tags: c#, jquery, confirm

How to call a conditional confirm box from c#.

I have 2 hidden fields and based on the condition I want to call confirm box.

After that I also want what user has pressed (clicked on yes or No).

**Design:-**

```
  <input type="submit" id="btnAddPaymentMethod" onserverclick="AddPaymentMethod_Click" runat="server" value="add payment method" />
```

**Code:-**

```
   protected void Next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
            if (hdnDefault.Value == hdnPrimary.Value) { return; }
            else
            {
            //open confirm box 
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "confirm", "confirm('Do you want to save new default payment method?');", true);
                    string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
                    if (confirmValue == "Yes")
                    {
                        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('You clicked YES!')", true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('You clicked NO!')", true);
                    }
            }
     }
```

I have tried below jQuery Code:-

```
 function Confirm(msg) {
            var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
            confirm_value.type = "hidden";
            confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
            if (confirm(msg)) {
                confirm_value.value = "Yes";
                $('#btnAddPaymentMethod').click();
            } else {
                confirm_value.value = "No";
            }
            document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you put condition in javascript / jquery where you can call confirm straightaway instead of server side code.

Comment: Try this Link @Sunny Singh
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Server-Side-Yes-No-Confirmation-Box-using-JavaScript.aspx

Comment: I have seen that article @jose but I didn't get any confirm box, its always showing 'You clicked NO!'..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void Next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (hdnDefault.Value == hdnPrimary.Value) { 
    return; 
  } else {
    //open confirm box 
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "confirm", "Confirm('Do you want to save new default payment method?');", true);
  }
}

protected void AddPaymentMethod_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
  if (confirmValue == "Yes") {
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('You clicked YES!')", true);
  } else {
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('You clicked NO!')", true);
  }
}

function Confirm(msg) {
  var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
  confirm_value.type = "hidden";
  confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
  confirm_value.value = confirm(msg)? "Yes" : "No";
  document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
  $('#btnAddPaymentMethod').click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not run your code. But when you have `runat="server"` for an input control it will append with the asp.net unique Id. So try to access the input control by it's name ending with `btnAddPaymentMethod` as below.

Change from `$('#btnAddPaymentMethod').click();` to `$('[id$=btnAddPaymentMethod]').click();`

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery code will open a confirm dialog, with an 'ok' and 'cancel' buttons.

Here an anchor tag with an id of myConfirmPageLink, when clicked, will ask for confirmation. If ok is clicked it proceeds to the target, and if cancel is clicked it stays on the same page.

```
$("a#myConfirmPageLink").click(function(){
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to go to that page/site ?");
});
```

This should be easy to modify for your purposes.